# Multiple cells testing the same condition in an or statement

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to see if any of a set of 4 cells satisfied a specific condition. Here is what I have as the worksheet function:

```
=IF(OR((D11,E11,F11,G11)>$I$6),"YES","NO")
```

However, I get a "#VALUE" error. Is there a way to test multiple cells against hte same condition without having to do a greater than for each one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this do?

```
=IF(MAX(D11:G11)>$I$6,"YES","NO")
```

Alternatively, if you are happy with TRUE or FALSE instead of "YES" or "NO" you can use an array formula:

```
{=OR(D11:G11)>$I$6)}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't even think of that!